# Change Title Text Color Of UIActivityController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying the title text color of the text that comes up when you you use a UIActivityController. The text reading, **"Tap to share with AirDrop"**. I would like to make it white rather than the default color which seem to be gray.

I have been looking for quite some time, and I'm sure there are like three lines of code out there to change this.

Attached image below:

[image]

Here is my existing code:

[image]

Comment: Do you need an answer for only iOS9 or do you need legacy iOS also?

Comment: Can you share the code where you're adding the title?

Comment: @AdamRush That's the thing, I'm not adding the title. It comes standard.

Comment: @JudeMichaelMurphy I can see the problem. You are adding a UIActivityViewController to a UIPopOverController, in the eyes of Apple this is bad. Basically it's the UIPopOverController that is setting this title. I think the correct solution is to display the UIActivityViewController directly from the button tapped on.

Comment: @AdamRush It will not work on an iPad if I don't set that to a UIPopOverController.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image. It's easier to read and reference.

Comment: @JudeMichaelMurphy it will, all you have to do is set as follows;

controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = rect;
controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
 
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

Comment: @AdamRush It changes the way it's presented, but the suggested color change doesn't work even when this is done, unfortunately.

Comment: @JudeMichaelMurphy That's how Apple say it should be presented, in terms of colour it will change the button text.

Answer (score 0):

The colour for UIActivityViewController is inherited from the applications tint colour by default.

**Try this;**

```
[activityController.view setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

You could create a category if this is used throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```